# Self-intersecting geometry errors when splitting polygons

Tags: qgis, shapefile, self-intersection

I'm having issues digitising in QGIS 2.18.20 on my mac. My normal strategy for digitising a habitat survey area is to create a (shapefile) polygon for my survey boundary, and split the shape repeatedly.  But at present no matter how simple the shape I can't seem to split it more than once due to self-intersecting geometry errors.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be because you are using the *split parts* tool instead of the *split features* tool. Below you'll see the button I mean.

[image: Advanced digitizing toolbar]

Comment: Thanks for your answer..  I tried that but I get the same behaviour with both tools.